# Show images from temp directory to end users

Tags: php, html, ajax, image

I am doing image rotate functionality. I am rotating the image and saving into tmp directory using

```
$rotate = imagerotate($source, 90, 0);
$rotatedTmpFile = tempnam('/tmp', 'rotatedThumbnailImage');
imagejpeg($rotate, $rotatedTmpFile ,100);
```

Files get created in tmp folder. But now I want to

1. read the content of tmp directory
2. Generate the url of tmp image file
3. Send that src as a response back to ajax call

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: PAdmin.roateImageUrl,
    data: {
        mediaId: id[1],
        src: src
    },
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(response) {
        img.attr('src', response);
    }
});
```

4. Show that rotated image to end user before uploading on S3 server.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure /tmp is not accessible via your webserver directly. You should either move from /tmp to a directory in your docroot, or alternatively encode the image in the html directly; using

```
$mime = mime_content_type($rotatedTmpFile);
$data = file_get_contents($rotatedTmpFile);
exit('data:' . $mime . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data));
```

this should work as an image-src but might be somewhat resource-expensive

Comment: Can you modify your answer with handling ajax response call?

Comment: @sAcH this should work with your ajax-script. If the server echo's the above, and the js puts in in img.src; it should work

Comment: Nopes. Its not working. I tried with multiple ways. like img.attr('src',base64_decode(response)), img.attr('src',response);

Comment: `img.attr('src',response);` should work; what does console.log(response) output?

Answer (score 2):

Got the solution with the help of @Sjon.

```
$.ajax({
    url: PAdmin.roateImageUrl,
    data: {mediaId:id[1],src: src},
    type: 'POST',
    success: 
        function(response){
            img.attr('src',response);
        }
});
```

In PAdmin.roateImageUrl:

> Note: Exception has not been handled in this code.

```
$rotate = imagerotate($source, 90, 0);
$rotatedTmpFile = tempnam('/tmp', 'rotatedThumbnailImage');
imagejpeg($rotate, $rotatedTmpFile ,100);
list($imageWidth, $imageHeight, $imageType) = getimagesize($rotatedTmpFile);
$type = image_type_to_mime_type($imageType);
$data = file_get_contents($rotatedTmpFile);
echo 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
exit;
```

Comment: no need to duplicate my solution, I have incorporated the exit in my answer, imo you can delete this duplicate

Answer (score -1):

Usually, you would use a `move_uploaded_file()` function to move your rotated image to some "temporary" web accessible folder (like "`images/temp/`").

You would generate a random name for the image (if required for security reasons) and you could get the URL easily by just appending the file name to "`/images/temp/`".